# litespeed php won't use latest version

Tags: php, litespeed

I'm trying to upgrade my PHP from version 5.6.40 to version 8.0 on a litespeed server.

I went to cpanel and changed the version. Creating a new file with just

```
<?php
phpinfo();
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
?>
```

displays version 8.0

However, my "real" file still shows the old version.

I've cleared the browser cache. I've tried a different browser. I've even tried accessing the page from my phone (instead of my dev computer). All show the old version.

Here is the top of the "real" file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Mary Lou Kostal - Artist</title>
<meta name="Keywords" content="tableau, painting, canvas, monotype">
<meta name="Description"
   content="Mary Lou Kostal - Abstract fine arts on linen and paper">

<?php include 'global.php'; setEra (); ?>
...
```

And, the top of global.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set ("display_errors", 1);
phpinfo();
...
```

Is there something I need to do differently ?

Comment: Are the two files (the new one you've just created and the old global.php) both server from the same webserver/virtualhost?

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a problem in .htaccess

Through cpanel, I used the `MultiPHP Manager` to upgrade PHP, which is the expected way to do so. This tool injects some code into .htacccess

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “alt-php80” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php80 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

which apparently overrides my handcoded statements:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

To solve this, I simply added `.html` to the end of the generated `AddHandler` line.

Whether this change will stick next time I run the config tool, I don't know.